# Future Date Selection in Jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have the following `JQuery Datepicker` in my page.

```
$("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          yearRange: '1901:2050',
          maxDate: new Date(),
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          showMonthAfterYear: true,
          inline: true,
          altField: "#<%= HiddenDate.ClientID %>",
          altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
              shouldsubmit = true;
              javascript: __doPostBack('<%= txtDate.ClientID %>', '');
          },
          onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
              shouldsubmit = false;
          }
      });
```

It limits my selection to the current date. How do I allow the user to select any future date?

Comment: The `new Date()` gives you today's date. So it's saying that the last day you can select is today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will limit the selection as you mentioned

```
maxDate: new Date(),
```

Remove it and you can select any date till the range you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can set future date limit as follow:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4zb6t/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set ***today date*** is future date ,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        minDate: -10, 
        maxDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zb6t/3/)**</kbd>

---

Another way you can set `+1M` `+10D` parameter,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        minDate: -10, 
        maxDate: "+1M +10D" 
    });
});
```

Check this <kbd>**demo jsfiddle**</kbd>

---

you can pass **yyyy, mm, dd** inside **date()** function to set future date,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        minDate: -10, 
        maxDate: new Date(2025, 01,01)
    });
});
```

Check this <kbd>**demo jsfiddle**</kbd>

Hope this help you!